# Marine invertebrate San Juan Islands, WA, USA

Tags: species-identification, entomology, marine-biology

I noticed a green-colored marine arthropod in harbor in the [US San Juan Islands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/San_Juan_Islands) (early July 2022, around noon), specifically Haro Strait, and took several pictures from the dock.

The bug was approximately 1 centimeter in length. I am guessing that it is algivorous (or algivore-vorous) based on the green color. It was in constant motion in sunlight, possibly hunting though it wasn't clear what it was going after (though the area was very algae-rich).

Apologies for the low quality images, some of these are stills from a movie (I had issues focusing because it was underwater and it was swimming around quite quickly).

Google image search was not very helpful, and neither was iNaturalist.

[image: green-colored marine arthropod]

[image: green-colored marine arthropod pic 2]

[image: green-colored marine arthropod pic 3]